# Sustitución del metodo split()

Tags: python-3.x

en otro foro alguien pregunto por una sustitución del método split() que recordamos que devolvía una lista con las palabras de un string utilizando una separacion que eligamos. y quería buscar otra forma sin utilizar ese método. elemplo:

input>>> casa arbol cama coche
out>>> ['casa','arbol','cama','coche']

os envío el código que he echo que funciona bien pero sé que python brilla por su simpleza y debe haber alguna manera mejor. Por si podeis echarle un vistazo y sabéis alguna otra manera.

```
def union(string,x,y):#funcion con tres argumentos, el string y dos posiciones para sacar la palabra e incluirla en la lista
  element=''
  while x<y:
    element+=string[x]
    x+=1
  lista.append(element)

def incorpora(string):#funcion donde recorre el strin para ir cortando antes del espacio mostrar las posiciones para que la función incorpora saque la palabra y la registre en la lista. en el primer while repite hasta que no halla espacios en el string de ahí que añadiese un espacio al final y el segundo while es el que manda a la funcion siempre que halla palabra y luego eliminamos la palabra del string.
  space=' '
  while space in string:
    final=len(string)
    indice=0
    inicio=0
    while indice<final:
      for i in string:
        if i==' ':
          indice=string.index(i)
      union(string,inicio, indice)
      string=string[indice+1:final]
      indice=final
        
lista=[]  
palabras=input("Ingrese una cadena: " )
palabras =palabras+' '#añadimos un espacio al final del string
sep=' '
incorpora(palabras)
for i in lista:
  if i in sep:
    lista.remove(i)
print(lista)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues claramente que hay una forma simplificada de hacerlo. Un ciclo `for` y el uso del método `index` es suficiente.

```py
def my_split(cadena, separador):
    resultado, n = [], None
    cadena += separador if separador in cadena else ""
    for n in range(cadena.count(separador)):
        i = cadena.index(separador)
        resultado.append(cadena[:i])
        cadena = cadena[i+1:]       
    return (resultado if n else [cadena])
```

En el `for` decimos que iteraremos según las veces que el separador se repita en la cadena. En cada iteración encontraremos el índice del elemento y entonces añadimos el trozo a la lista y luego sobreescribimos el valor de `cadena`. Al finalizar el ciclo `for` retornamos la lista con los elementos separados pero retornamos `[cadena]` en caso el separador no se encuentre en la cadena.

**Probamos**

```py
cadena = "casa arbol cama coche out"

print(my_split(cadena, " "))
```

**Resultado**

```
['casa', 'arbol', 'cama', 'coche', 'out']
```

Obviamente deberíamos de colocar un `if` para el caso que no se pase un separador, es decir `""`.

Comment: Buenas he probado y sólo me mete la ultima palabra en la lista

Comment: si, había omitido algo, pero ya lo corregí

Answer (score 1):

Una solución usando expresiones regulares:

```
def my_split(cadena, separador):
    exp = f"([^{separador}]+)"
    return re.findall(exp, cadena)
```

Supongamos que usamos la coma como separador. Entonces, `exp` queda reducida a `([^,]+)`, que es una expresión regular que reconoce y captura un grupo de uno o más caracteres que **no** sean coma. Al encerrar la expresión entre paréntesis, la *capturamos*. La función retorna una lista con todas las *capturas*, es decir, todas aquellas partes del texto que cumplieron con la expresión.

#### Demo

```
import re

def my_split(cadena, separador):
    exp = f"([^{separador}]+)"
    return re.findall(exp, cadena)

tests = [
    ("la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta", " "),
    ("123,456,678,,443,34", ","),
    ("el valor, 123.45, descontado", ","),
    ("ab^cd^ef", "^"),
    ("45*677*89", "*")
]

for (cadena, separador) in tests:
    m = my_split(cadena, separador)
    print(m)
```

produce

```
['la', 'mona', 'jacinta', 'se', 'ha', 'puesto', 'una', 'cinta']
['123', '456', '678', '443', '34']
['el valor', ' 123.45', ' descontado']
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
['45', '677', '89']
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si es la mejor forma, pero me centré en la velocidad.

###### Código

```
def my_split_dante(cadena, separador, maxsplit=-1):
    index = 0
    len_separador = len(separador)
    lista = []

    if(maxsplit == -1):
        maxsplit = float('inf')
    
    while True:
        # buscamos en la cadena la subcadena de separador desde la ultima coincidencia. Si no hubo coincidencias antes, busca desde el principio.
        index_nuevo = cadena.find(separador, index)

        # Si no se encontró ninguna nueva coincidencia, agrega a la lista una pedazo de la cadena que va desde
        # la ultima coincidencia hasta el final y se devuelve la lista.
        if(index_nuevo == -1):
            break
        else:
            lista.append(cadena[index:index_nuevo])
            index = index_nuevo+len_separador

            # Le resta 1 a maxsplit por cada coincidencia encontrada.
            maxsplit -= 1

            # Cuando maxsplit vale 0, el bucle es interrumpido.
            if(maxsplit == 0):
                break

    lista.append(cadena[index:])
    return lista

print("my_split_dante con el parametro maxsplit", my_split_dante("hola mundo soy dante s.", " ", maxsplit=2))
print("my_split_dante SIN el parametro maxsplit", my_split_dante("hola mundo soy dante s.", " "))
```

###### produce

```
my_split_dante con el parametro maxsplit ['hola', 'mundo', 'soy dante s.']
my_split_dante SIN el parametro maxsplit ['hola', 'mundo', 'soy', 'dante', 's.']
```